# What is a use case for kubernetes job?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

I'm looking to fully understand the jobs in kubernetes.

I have successfully create and executed a job, but I do not see the use case.

Not being able to rerun a job or not being able to actively listen to it completion makes me think it is a bit difficult to manage.

Anyone using them? Which is the use case?

Thank you.

Comment: Its like cron job in unix. you can use it for batch processing. I am not using it now.

Comment: Kubernetes has a CronJob type so you should probably use that instead if you're looking for crons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A job retries pods until they complete, so that you can tolerate errors that cause pods to be deleted.

If you want to run a job repeatedly and periodically, you can use [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/).

Some Helm Charts use Jobs to run install, setup, or test commands on clusters, as part of installing services. ([Example](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/7b1b8e7ac3f49330d0a4c2df9a6c0e4d9d296c17/stable/spinnaker/templates/hooks/delete-jobs.yaml)).

If you save the YAML for the job then you can re-run it by deleting the old job an creating it again, or by editing the YAML to change the name (or use e.g. `sed` in a script).

You can watch a job's status with this command:

`kubectl get jobs myjob -w`

The `-w` option watches for changes. You are looking for the `SUCCESSFUL` column to show `1`.

Here is a shell command loop to wait for job completion (e.g. in a script):
`until kubectl get jobs myjob -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Complete")].status}' | grep True ; do sleep 1 ; done`

Comment: in k8s documentation they have given example of task distribution for parallel processing https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/ . I am intrigued does people uses it for such type of work on production env with job?

Comment: Like i can think of a use case where i have deployed let's say my kafka consumers as a pod but not via job, normal deployment. they are just running. And new pods can be created when lets say memory or cpu consumption exceed.

Answer (score 1):

One of the use case can be to take a backup of a DB. But as already mentioned that are some overheads to run a job e.g. When a Job completes the Pods are not deleted . so you need to manually delete the job(which will also delete the pods created by job). so recommended option will be to use Cron instead of Jobs